# Select cell ranges and then print

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following code which works fine:

```
Sheets("File1").Select
Range("B2:J56").Select
Selection.PrintOut Copies:=1, Collate:=True
```

But I need to print several ranges and the pages should comply with the following formats:

- every selection should fit an A4 paper
- double-sided
- columns adjusted in one page so that the content fits entirely in the page width
- quality print of 600 dpi
- margins centred (horizontally and vertically)
- pages should include a header "This data was collected a year ago"

After struggling on the internet to no avail, I have recorded a macro but there are still many errors when I try to reproduce the code snippet,
 specially *in time execution error #1004* in line `ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = "$B$2:$J$56;$L$2:$T$37;$V$2:$AH$37"` and *print communication method failed*.

**[EDIT]:** Solution implemented below

```
 Sub RECORDED_Macro_Print_test()

     Application.ScreenUpdating = False

         Sheets("File1").Select
         Range("B2:J83,L2:T37,V2:AO92").Select
         Range("V2").Activate
         ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = "$B$2:$J$83;$L$2:$T$37;$V$2:$AO$92" ' <----- Fix it by replacing ';' by ',' as suggested by the user 'Siva' 
         Application.PrintCommunication = False
         With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
             .PrintTitleRows = ""    ' <----- Not necessary
             .PrintTitleColumns = "" ' <----- Not necessary
             .LeftHeader = ""        ' <----- Not necessary
             .CenterHeader = "This data was collected a year ago"
             .RightHeader = ""       ' <----- Not necessary
             .LeftFooter = ""        ' <----- Not necessary
             .CenterFooter = ""      ' <----- Not necessary
             .RightFooter = ""       ' <----- Not necessary
             .LeftMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.511811023622047)
             .RightMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.511811023622047)
             .TopMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.78740157480315)
             .BottomMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.78740157480315)
             .HeaderMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.31496062992126)
             .FooterMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.31496062992126)
             .PrintHeadings = False
             .PrintGridlines = False
             .PrintComments = xlPrintNoComments
             .PrintQuality = 600
             .CenterHorizontally = True
             .CenterVertically = True
             .Orientation = xlPortrait
             .Draft = False
             .PaperSize = xlPaperA4
             .FirstPageNumber = xlAutomatic
             .Order = xlDownThenOver
             .BlackAndWhite = False
             .Zoom = False
             .FitToPagesWide = 1
             .FitToPagesTall = False
             .PrintErrors = xlPrintErrorsDisplayed
             .OddAndEvenPagesHeaderFooter = False
             .DifferentFirstPageHeaderFooter = False
             .ScaleWithDocHeaderFooter = True
             .AlignMarginsHeaderFooter = True
              .EvenPage.LeftHeader.Text = ""    ' <----- Not necessary
              .EvenPage.CenterHeader.Text = ""  ' <----- Not necessary
              .EvenPage.RightHeader.Text = ""   ' <----- Not necessary
              .EvenPage.LeftFooter.Text = ""    ' <----- Not necessary
              .EvenPage.CenterFooter.Text = ""  ' <----- Not necessary
              .EvenPage.RightFooter.Text = ""   ' <----- Not necessary
              .FirstPage.LeftHeader.Text = ""   ' <----- Not necessary
              .FirstPage.CenterHeader.Text = "" ' <----- Not necessary
              .FirstPage.RightHeader.Text = ""  ' <----- Not necessary
              .FirstPage.LeftFooter.Text = ""   ' <----- Not necessary
              .FirstPage.CenterFooter.Text = "" ' <----- Not necessary
              .FirstPage.RightFooter.Text = ""  ' <----- Not necessary
         End With
         Application.PrintCommunication = True  ' <----- Remove this line to fix it. This is an error issue
         Selection.PrintOut Copies:=1, Collate:=True
     End Sub
```

To record the macro I have basically selected all the ranges I needed by holding the SHIFT key, then I defined the print area, then pressed print, specified all constraints in the dialog box and voilà. How to get it to work?

Comment: OK. Four hours+ looking to solve this problem and I get a -1 ? If the answer seems to be so easy, please inform the solution. I would be really greateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your code line

```
ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = "$B$2:$J$56;$L$2:$T$37;$V$2:$AH$37"
```

with

```
ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = "$B$2:$J$56,$L$2:$T$37,$V$2:$AH$37"
```

I have tried it in my machine and that line didn't give any error after replacing

Comment: The macro record keeps a record of the actual status, not only including it as part of the final code snippet, but also increasing it with information that you no longer need, as for example: the previous quality print was originally set to 72 dpi and I had to manually erase several lines. After fixing the semi-colon issue and deleting the `.PrintCommunication = True`, it worked. Thank you a lot.